# In Django where are defined the attributes short_description, boolean and admin_order_field?

Tags: django, boolean, models

I'm new with Python and Django, I know this is probably a stupid question, but I'm not able to find the answer, on Google, on DJango docs and in #django channel, on Freenode.

On the official docs, here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial02/ there is this piece of code:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    # ...
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'
```

The question: where are defined the attributes admin_order_field, boolean and short_description? They comes from models.Model? why i'm not able to find with dir()? and there's a way to find an attribute or method in Python, searching recursively in all Python, Django or a package like the "tree" in Unix-Like systems?

Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1):

They're defined right there, in your code.

In Python it's not necessary to declare attributes of an object in advance. It's perfectly normal to add arbitrary attributes to an object whenever you like. In this case, these are not pre-defined attributes of Model: they are extra attributes of the *method* `was_published_recently`, which are defined ad-hoc but which Python's admin app will use if they are found.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, so these attributes are defined on the fly, by me, but if i change short_description, with short_desc or something.foo, doesn't work, because django looks for these attributes, if aren't found fallback right? So the questione come back, there is a reference or a doc where to find what django look for? or exist only these 3 attributes?

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in document that you read it, these attributes are defined in `models.py` of `app`.

> You can improve that by giving that method (in polls/models.py)

and if you get `dir()` in `django shell` you can see these attributes. like this:

```
dir(Question.was_published_recently)
```

Comment: Thanks, your're right, but my question was a bit different, take a look to my comment up there :)

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the show, but i was recently asking this myself and did a little research.

Important finding: There is now a decorator `@admin.display` for this, which is actually documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.display).

Actual attribute lookups are scattered at different places:

| Parameter | File |
| --- | --- |
| `boolean` | .../django/contrib/admin/helpers.py |
| `short_description` | .../django/contrib/admin/utils.py |
| `admin_order_field` | .../django/contrib/admin/views/main.py |